# PHP / MySQLI won't update properly

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, sql-update

**PHP / MySQLI**

```
 $query = $conn->query(
        "SELECT
        cart.cart_id,
        cart.user_ip,
        cart.cart_amount,
        cart.fk_product_id,
        products.product_id,
        products.prod_amount
    FROM
        cart
    INNER JOIN
        products
    ON
        cart.fk_product_id = products.product_id
    WHERE
        fk_product_id = '{$productID}' AND user_ip = '{$ip}'
    ");

    $item = $query->fetch_assoc():

    $FKproductID = $item['fk_product_id'];
    $FKproductID = iSQLsecure($objConnection, $FKproductID);
    $FKproductID = trim($FKproductID);

    $CartAmount = $item['cart_amount'];
    $CartAmount = iSQLsecure($objConnection, $CartAmount);
    $CartAmount = trim($CartAmount);

    $ProductAmount = $item['prod_amount'];
    $ProductAmount = iSQLsecure($objConnection, $ProductAmount);
    $ProductAmount = trim($ProductAmount);

    $one = 1;

    $add_amount = $CartAmount + $one;
    $remove_amount = $ProductAmount - $one;

    if($FKproductID == $productsID) {
        $update_cart_item = $objConnection->query("UPDATE cart SET cart_amount = '{$add_amount}' WHERE fk_product_id = '{$productID}' AND user_ip = '{$ip}'");
        $update_product_amount = $objConnection->query("UPDATE products SET prod_amount = '{$remove_amount}' WHERE product_id = '{$productID}'");
    } else {
        $add_item = $objConnection->query("INSERT INTO cart (user_ip, add_amount, fk_product_id) VALUES ('{$ip}', '{$add_amount}', '{$productID}')");
        $update_product_amount = $objConnection->query("UPDATE products SET prod_amount = '{$remove_amount}' WHERE product_id = '{$productID}'");
    }

    $objConnection->close();
```

**My Problem**

```
$update_product_amount = $objConnection->query("UPDATE products SET prod_amount = '{$remove_ProductAmount}' WHERE product_id = '{$productID}'");
```

I use this two places `if($FKproductID == $productsID) { /*HERE1*/ } else { /*AND HERE2*/}`

For some reason it works in "*HERE1*" but not in "*HERE2*"?

**If item is not in cart**

It will insert it into my "cart" database and update "products" amount value. It is supposed to remove **1** from the current product amount (10 becomes 9). Instead it turns 10 into -1.

**If item is in cart**

It updates perfectly and turns 10 into 9. The code is the exact same but gives two different results?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the above code isn't complete, since some variable name is inconsistent (`$remove_amount` vs `$remove_ProductAmount`) and yet your code run fine on some case.

For the queries, why don't you just subtract the amount on update query? Something like

```
UPDATE table SET field = field - 1 WHERE x = y
```

Even if the number `1` is dynamic, it's safer to generate the number on variables then cast it to integer. On worst case, it would be converted to zero (which can be easily added on your `if()` as additional validation).

I also recommend using debugger. Something like [Kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/) or [PsySH](http://psysh.org/#usage) would suffice if you don't want to trouble yourself with setting up XDebug.

Comment: Forgot to change `$remove_ProductAmount` to `$remove_amount`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be with your `INNER JOIN`. From what I can tell, if the item isn't in your cart, then the `cart.fk_product_id` won't exist, and therefore the query will return an empty object.

If you have error display turned off (likely in the `php.ini` with `display_errors = Off`), non-existant array keys will be treated as null during equations.

When it comes time to do the equations, php will convert `null` to `integer(0)` which results in `0 - 1 = -1` if it fails the if statement.

Have you tried to output the returned object of the query? You can do this by using:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($item); echo "</pre>";
```

(the <pre> tag makes it a bit more readable).

Also, check the status of your httpd/apache error log if you have `log_errors` turned on.